# External Content Types are not available. Contact your system administrator - BCS - User profile sync

Tags: bcs, external-content-type

I'm trying to setup a BCS connection from a SQL view -> user profile properties.

I've created the external content type and got the right view. I also set the "set object permission", checked all the checkboxes.

The problem is when I'm trying to create the BCS in user profile synchronization connection it says "External Content Types are not available. Contact your system administrator."

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: How did you managed to integrate your on premise data to SharePoint, i've been jumping from site to site but haven't found any practical example and this scenario is practically the same i am trying to resolve. Do you have any resources you can share as reference? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong user in "set object permission", just check ther persmission and it would work!